# How to know return types of methods in xcode? - iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

while typing in Xcode, (objective - c for iPhone dev)

Suppose I write

[mySprite

[[here mySprite is an object of sprite class ( cocos2d - for game development ). ]]

After writing this, if I press ## esc ## key.

It will show me all the methods.

Lets take an example,

If I am using [mySprite position]; method,

How can I came to know, what actually ## position ## method returns?

Let's take an example of other Integrated development environment.

.net provides a tool tip, when we press ctrl + space, it will show all the properties & methods with it's signature & other hints.
Does x Code provides the same?

( actually, Before being a iphone developer - i was .net trainee developer, So, actually I am expecting something like .net  )

Comment: .net provides a tool tip, when we press ctrl + space, it will show all the properties & methods with it's signature & other hints.
Does x Code provides the same?

Comment: IIRS, XCode provides IntelliSense-style help when you hit the `ESC` key.

Comment: But ESC key doesn't tell the return type of methods - that is already added in my question....

Comment: It doesn't have that level of Intellisense-type behavior, no. For that you're still in the world of using the documentation -- preferably the online docs at developer.apple.com.

Comment: See the answer below, sir - @john rudy. I wanted just the return types & arguments. & @cory Kilger - gave the exact answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode, open Preferences, go to Code Sense, and check "Show arguments in pop-up list".  Now the list will show return types and parameters.

Comment: Yup, and I just checked 3.1 and the option exists.

Comment: But, Problem is something different. When we press ESC, we are getting the entire list. Suppose we are using sprite class object, it should list only sprite class instance level methods.

Comment: It seems to work for me.  If I do type "[Sprite " and hit escape it takes me to spriteWithFile:, whereas if I type "[[Sprite alloc] " and hit escape it takes me to initWithFile:.

Comment: Yup ! it's working as you said. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge, sir.